# Newbie - read 49 excel sheets into dataframe

Tags: python, excel, database, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel workbook with 49 sheets (all same columns, different data). I want to load this data into a database, by creating one csv file from the 49 sheets. My plan is to read and concatenate each sheet into a "master" dataframe. Then I will write this dataframe a csv file, which I can load into a database (probably mySQL).

I have successfully read the first 3 sheets, one at a time, as follows:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Pages 1-49.xlsx')
xls.sheet_names
pdf_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name='page 1',skiprows=1)
pdf.append(pdf_next)
```

I execute this code 2 more times (not shown here) and have 3 dataframes named pdf_1, pdf_2, and pdf 3.

I then concatenate these three dataframes as follows:

```
voters = pd.concat([pdf_1, pdf_2, pdf_3],ignore_index='false')
```

Everything is "working" - I have a single dataframe - but I have a total of 150 worksheets. How do I go from one-at-a-time to a loop?

I want one dataframe containing 150 worksheets of data.

Probably a simple task but I've spent several long days to get this far. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4):

you need to use a ["for loop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#1991:_Python).
May I suggest something like the following:

```
df_list=[]
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Pages 1-49.xlsx')

for x in range(150):
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name='page {}'.format(x+1),skiprows=1)
    df_list.append(df)


voters = pd.concat(df_list,ignore_index='false')
```

alternatively, the for loop can be replaced like the below if `xls.sheet_names` is a list.

```
df_list=[]
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name,skiprows=1)
    df_list.append(df)
```

Comment: Your first (for loop) suggestion seems to be working. It created a 'bunch' of UNNAMED columns, but I dropped them and assigned the "clean" dataframe to a "clean_voters" dataframe. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
# this give you a dictionary of dataframe
# {sheet_name: sheet_df}
dfs = pd.read_excel('play.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
```

With my toy xlsx:

```
            A    B    C
Sheet1 0  1.0  2.0  3.0
       1  4.0  5.0  6.0
Sheet2 0  1.0  2.0  3.0
       1  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply !

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply !

I "changed" your code to the following:

    dfs = pd.read_excel('Pages 1-49.xlsx', sheet_name=None,skiprows=1)
    pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)

It looks like it works EXCEPT for inserting a bunch of UNNAMED columns. I'm still investigating, but maybe you've run into this before? All of the worksheets appear to have identical columns.

I have all the columns I need, but I have a bunch of added UNNAMED columns. Is there a way just to drop the UNNAMED columns? Or prevent them before they are created?

Comment: Why did you `skiprows=1`? Don't your sheets start with column names on top?

Comment: The first row of each sheet is an unneeded header name for the sheet. The second row contains the column headers.

Comment: I get the 10 columns I want, followed by a "bunch" of UNNAMED columns, populated by NaN values. How do I drop - or not create - the UNNAMED columns.

Comment: Did you try `pd.read_excel('Pages 1-49.xlsx', sheet_name=None,skiprows=1, usecols=10)`?

Comment: dfs = pd.read_excel('Pages 1-49.xlsx', sheet_name=None,skiprows=1,usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

I still get the UNNAMED columns ):

Comment: usecols=10 is deprecated. Told me to use a list of column numbers (usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: There must be something wrong with the excel file. Without the file, I can't tell exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Teng's suggestion seems to be working. You might want to look at my reply to him. THANK YOU for your help.

Comment: Basically his answer also gives the UNAMED columns, and you still need to drop them after merge. So it's likely due to your excel file.

Comment: Could be. I'm doing initial data validation/exploration. BTW, I used the solution (teng's) that I could get to work, not necessarily the better solution. I'm a rookie. Thanks for your time and help.